# How can I intercept/prevent a property from being modified with (fluent) NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, properties, fluent-nhibernate

If I have a model (class) called Employee, how can I intercept/modify property changes?

For example:

```
Employee e = session.Get<Employee>(1);
e.Status = EmployeeStatus.Fired;
```

How can I intercept e.Status from being modified and either change it to a different value or throw an error, etc?

I know I can use events (ie. IPreUpdateEventListener) to modify the state but I'd like to do it immediately when a property is being assigned/modified if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this behavior using NHibernate Interceptors, take a look to [this article](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html).